# How to handle alerts while converting RTF files to txt files using win32com.client

Tags: python, win32com

I'm trying to convert tens of thousands RTF files to txt format using win32com.client.

```
wordapp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
doc = wordapp.Documents.Open(rtf_file, False, False, False)
doc.SaveAs(txt_file, FileFormat = 2)
```

I encounter the following notification:

"The document may contain text content that will be lost upon conversion to the chosen encoding. To preserve this content , click No to exit this dialog box,and then choose another encoding that supports the languages in this document. Do you want to continue saving the document? Yes/No"

I want to continue and would like to click Yes. Is there a way to handle this? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Try `wordapp.DisplayAlerts = False` before you save the file.

Comment: Works like charm. Please paste it as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent alerts from displaying, you can turn them off via your wordapp call.

This should work;

```
wordapp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')

# Add this
wordapp.DisplayAlerts = False

doc = wordapp.Documents.Open(rtf_file, False, False, False)
doc.SaveAs(txt_file, FileFormat = 2)
```